# How can a function return both array and class in php

Tags: php

**example 1 :**

```php
<?php
$class=new class_test();
$users=$class->db('users')->where(['id','>','1'],['id','<','10']);
?>
```

**example 2 :**

```
<?php
class test{
    function text($text){

    }
    function remove($text){

    }
}
$test=new test();
$text1=$test->text('my text 1')->remove('my')->remove('text'); // 1
$text2=$test->text('my other text')->remove('other')->remove('text');// my
?>
```

I want the function return an array and also the class but dont know how to make it work!
Please help me to improve my code...

Comment: you can't return more than one thing from a function. there's no `return(val1, val2)` in php.  some languages, like perl, have support for detecting HOW the return value gets used, so you can return the appropriate type on-the-fly. php doesn't (though maybe 7 has something along those lines - not very familiar with the v7 changes yet).

Comment: What do you mean return class? The class name? Do you mean object?

Comment: that being said, you CAN return an object, and implement the various magic methods like __toString() so the object can "transform" itself into a different type of structure on the fly.

Comment: @Marc the usual method is to pass parameters by reference for return values.

Comment: You can make your class implement the `Iterable` interface, so that the caller can loop over it as if it's an array.

Answer (score 1):

Each function can return only one value at the time, so the common approach to work this around is to return `array` (or `object`, yet returning array is clearly simpler):

```
<?php

function foo() {
   $cls = new class_test();
   return array(
             'class' => $cls,
             'users' => $cls->db('users')->where(['id','>','1'],['id','<','10']);
}
```

PS: class name you use -> `class_test` is not really following common standards. I suggest to stick to mainstream with that: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/

Answer (score 0):

well the best thing for your code is to return array of objects, if the result of the where are many rows then you will have array with many objects ,but if the result of the where is a one row then you will have array that has one object only.

another solution to create another function called "Find" so find will return only one object, and "where" will always return array